# Как будет правильно: с тире: Лев Толстой - "Война и мир", или без тире: Лев Толстой "Война и мир"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как будет правильно:
с тире:
Лев Толстой - "Война и мир",
или без тире:
Лев Толстой "Война и мир",
или можно и так и так?

Например если название группы вконтакте. Или можно писать с тире, и без тире в любом контексте?

Благодарю за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Если это заголовок, то, думаю, можно обойтись запятой, в тире нет необходимости. В других же ситуациях зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы называете книгу, принято после имени автора ставить точку. Название книги с заглавной в кавычках. Лев Толстой. "Война и мир."